# RAFT: how candidate term change?

Tags: raft

In the picture step b, s5 is elected as leader with term 3. How this 3 comes from ? 
In the paper, when a follower gets message from leader encounter timeout, it will increments its term and turn to a candidate state. So i think the term is 2, and it can still win the election to become leader. Because the node s3 and s4 will vote for it.

[image: raft]

Answer (score 0):

The description to the picture has a single indicator for term: at step B the term is three; this means that at step A the term is 2. As simple as that. Based in the description, it seems this picture clarifies some previous example and in that example the term got to 2 somehow.

Few observations on the picture to avoid any confusion.

The picture itself has no indication of current term for either step. Horizontal numbers are index, not term. The picture would be better if the author would use [term, value] for each index.

We know the term is 3 as step B. This means that the term became 4 when S1 was reelected. And the rest of the picture explains why d1 won't happen and value (2) accepted by S1 in term 4 and accepted my majority won't ever be lost - which is the main property of the protocol - if a value is accepted by majority, the value won't be lost.

Quick note: a value accepted by majority won't be lost, but the term of that value may change. In other words - every index contains a tuple [term, value]. If a specific value is accepted by majority, then the leader and majority of followers will have same [term, value] for the same index. If the leader fails before issuing commit, then the new leader will emerge and will re-propose the same value with a new term. So as soon as a value is accepted by majority, the value is to stay, even if term will change.